# Spring Boot 1.3.5: expanding variables within application.properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

We are using Spring Boot 1.3.5, which loads external `application.properties` using `@PropertySource("file:C:/tmp/application.properties")`. Here is how `application.properties` looks like:

```
env=prod
instance=EAST
emailSubject=${env}-${instance}: An error occurred
```

The code is able to see/get the correct values for `env` and `instance` variables, but the `emailSubject` variable is not getting substituted. And when we print it in the code, it shows

```
"${env}-${instance}: An error occurred"
```

How to make `emailSubject` be correctly substituted to show

```
"prod-EAST: An error occurred"
```

Comment: Are you certain you don't have any other configuration, either Spring or Maven/Gradle, that might interfere with this? As far as I can tell, this is supposed to work. Also, how do you print it in the code?

Comment: Hi @thomas-kåsene, sorry for the late response. 1. There are no other .properties file in the project 2. We are using maven, so we do have pom.xml, but as such i don't know which library/property could be interfering with this? 3. We do have config xml which is used by Spring Batch - to configure the job and another config xml that simply defines the beans - but no property there seems to be related to configuration

Comment: For printing, we are simply using our config class which reads properties and prints them(using logger) at application startup. All simple properties like env, instance are being printed correctly. But the emailSubject is the one not doing substitution.

Comment: Is it possible to provide an actual code example where you try to print the property in question?

Comment: @ThomasKåsene thank you!! the issue was even though its a Spring project, the colleague who wrote the code, loaded properties the old java way (using java.util.properties in a static block), since he wanted to load these properties ahead of few other things, which was not happening in Spring (or our team was not able to do). Your hint solved the issue, since java.util.Properties is just a simple file read with separation of key/value, this cannot be achieved without writing some custom tweaks. i'll have to handle it in the code. Please post your answer,so i can accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing much more about how it's set up, and seeing as the contents of the properties-file you posted is valid, I'll have to assume there's something wrong with how the contents is being read or used.